# cmake link executable and aalib library

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to link aalib to my cmake executable, and can't get it working. This is my first time using CMake, and I can't get aalib working. I installed aalib through `add-apt-repository ppa:aalib && apt install libaa1 libaa1-dev libaa-bin`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(untitled1 main.cpp)

find_package(aa_lib REQUIRED)

link_libraries(untitled1 aa_lib)
```

returns

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findaa_lib.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "aa_lib", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "aa_lib" with any
  of the following names:

    aa_libConfig.cmake
    aa_lib-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "aa_lib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "aa_lib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "aa_lib"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Comment: Well, are these files somewhere present with that lib you downloaded and installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the [list of files in the `libaa1` package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libaa1-dev/filelist) we can make the following observations:

- No file with the `.cmake` file extension is present. This prevents the use of `find_package`, at least without writing one on your own find script/package configuration file.
- The header file is installed at `/usr/include/aalib.h`; `/usr/include` should be part of the default include dirs, so we don't need to adjust the include dirs.
- The shared library is installed at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaa.so`. `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` is searched by default by the linker for libraries, so specifying the full library path or additional link directories is not necessary. Furthermore based on this we can tell that the name of the library to provide to the linker is `aa`.

This means you should be able to link the library using the following `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(untitled1)

add_executable(untitled1 main.cpp)

# specify a target specific minimum here instead of globablly specifying the choice
target_compile_features(untitled1 PRIVATE cxx_std_17) 

# add the following list of libraries to the libraries linked to target untitled1:
#   * aa
target_link_libraries(untitled1 PRIVATE aa)
```

**Note:**

I've replaced

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
...

link_libraries(untitled1 aa_lib)
```

With target specific equivalents. `link_libraries(untitled1 aa_lib)` only applies to cmake targets created specified after the cmake command and it would also try to link `untitled1` ***to*** such a target.

```
target_compile_features(untitled1 PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

is not an exact equivalent for setting the C++ standard, but rather provides a lower bound that could be overwritten by setting `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` as a cache variable during configuration. I prefer this approach, since you could decide to go with C++20 during configuration.